# How to handle browser back button when the user is logged in grails app?

Tags: grails

I want that whenever any user is logged into my grails app and as soon as he presses the browser back button he should be automatically redirected to landing page(after login one).
The code I am using on back button is :

```
var oldURL = document.referrer;
            alert(oldURL);
            var url1="http://localhost:8080/interviewbuddy/";
            var url2="http://localhost:8080/interviewbuddy/signup/signup";
            var url3="http://localhost:8080/interviewbuddy/login/auth";
            if(oldURL==url1||oldURL==url2||oldURL==url3){
                window.location="http://localhost:8080/interviewbuddy/company/dashboard";
            }
```

On my view gsp. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle it with javascript or jquery specifically

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
  var direction = data.state.direction;
  if (direction == 'back') {
    // redirect to landing page
    window.location="http://localhost:8080/interviewbuddy/company/dashboard";
  }
  if (direction == 'forward') {
    // do something else
  }
});
```